# Why is log4j rollingPolicy and triggeringPolicy ignored (log4j.xml config)?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have asked similar question regarding the log4j.properties configuration. I thought I should try xml, but it also does not work:

.properties question:
[Why is log4j rollingPolicy and triggeringPolicy ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825149/why-is-log4j-rollingpolicy-and-triggeringpolicy-ignored)

I want my log files to be zipped after every day and also in case they exceed a certain size. I use log4j 1.2.17.

```
implementation group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
```

Below you can see my log4j.xml file. The log file is created and is named as configured, but it is never zipped the next day or in case size exceeds 1MB. It always writes in the same file. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="rollingFile" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy
                class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="ActiveFileName" value="/Users/me/logs/test/log-file.log" />
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/Users/me/logs/test/log-file.log.%d{dd-MMM}.log.zip" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB" />
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value ="debug"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Does [How to combine log4j daily log rotation with filesize based rotation and maxbackup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67124080/11748454) answers your question? The `SizeBaseTriggeringPolicy` triggers a rollover when the file becomes larger the 1 MB, but the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` only performs a rollover if the date changed.

Comment: BTW: the max file size should be `1048576` instead of `1MB`, since the parameter must be a `long`.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz Thanks for the advice on the max file size, now it creates a new file when max size is reached, but it does not create a new file every day, only if max file size is reached as well. I can not use the response from the other question, because I can not add new code to that project. I have acces only to a log config)
Well looks like I can't fix that then. Job done :D

Comment: You can mention [CVE-2019-17571](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-17571/) and convince your team leader to migrate to Log4j 2.x (although the vulnerability does not apply to your usage scenario :-)).